# HTML input checkbox value as a php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to have an multidimensional array as the value of a checkbox kind of like the following.

Any alternatives that will get the same result would be helpful.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[][coursecode]" value="array("coursecode"=>"MG30012","year"=>"13")" />
```

Array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [coursecode] => FGB-NNE-MP [year] => 14 ) [1] => Array ( [coursecode] => NUV-PGE-NS [year] => 15 ) )
```

Comment: These thread might help you... [Passing Array from HTML to PHP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897490/passing-array-data-from-an-html-form-to-php-array-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can see why you might want an alternative.

I would suggest that you have a single dimensional array, and pass an easily parsable string to it.

**For instance:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="MG30012_13" />
```

**And then in your php:**

```
<?php
$courseValues = array(); //multimensional array;

foreach($_POST['courses'] as $course) {
    $courseValues[] = explode('_', $course);
}

?>
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT.  this is exactly what I needed.  I really appreciate the help.